# Jwplayer change orientation to device orientation on full screen event javascript

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, jwplayer

I am trying to override the app default orientation for the jwplayer. I am developing app in ionic 1 and my app orientation is portrait. There is jwplayer in one of the page where I want to rotate the player to device orientation if user click the full screen button.
There is a event `jwplayer().on('fullscreen')`.
The player need the override the app default orientation from portrait to device orientation when this event gets fired.

I don't want to change the app orientation to default.
Only change jwplayer orientation to device orientation when fullscreen event is fired.

Comment: Maybe you can try to use https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-screen-orientation on the event. And switch back to portrait when the jwplayer is closed.

Comment: Thanks it helped